# Why is form submitted by JavaScript not being submitted

Tags: javascript, html

Why doesn't my JavaScript fire, the checkprogress form button works if I manually click it, but it doesn't automatically fire, my JavaScript is meant to fire 5 seconds after page is displayed

This is the end of the html page
...

```
<form action="/check_progress" name="check_progress">
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Check Progress">
    </p>
</form>
<form action="/pause">
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Pause">
    </p>
</form>
<script>function checkprogress() { setTimeout(5000); document.getElementsByName('check_progress').submit(); } </script></body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should also look at the documentation for `setTimeout`. It needs to be **outside** your function, not inside it.

Comment: you need to name the inputs in your form that you wish to submit automatically  `name="key_name"`

Comment: All Im trying to do is submit form to server after 5 seconds, server will then create new page with updated status. This works if I manually click on the Check Progress button but not if I rely on the Javascript, I dont atcually even want the Check Progress button I just want the request to be made to the server after five seconds.

Comment: You could add an event for page load then use a timeout to submit the form. I don't actually know JS well enough so this can probably be improved but does work.

`document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() { setTimeout(function() { document.check_progress.submit(); }, 5000); })`

Comment: @Quentin I dont understand why duplicate, form name is check_progress, function checkprogress refers to that name correctly ?

Comment: @PaulTaylor — Umm. Nothing in the duplicate question suggests that you are using the wrong *name*. Try reading the accepted answer again.

Comment: @Quentin, I have chnaged so form now has id of check_progress and use document.getElementById(), and added an alert() at start of Javascript function but still nothing happens !

Comment: "You should also look at the documentation for setTimeout. It needs to be outside your function, not inside it." (You never call the function!)

Comment: @Quentin Ive removed it so now have function checkprogress() { alert('fred'); document.getElementById('check_progress').submit(); } but it doesnt even display the alert

Comment: @Jerry — Utter rubbish. There is no practical limit to the number of form elements you can have.

Comment: Is that what is breaking the Javascript, because both forms seem to work fine and it makes sense to be rather than cramming different tasks into the same form

Comment: @PaulTaylor —You still aren't calling the function

Comment: @Quentin I see what you mean now , how do call it, I tried this but didn't work - <script>function checkprogress() { alert('fred'); document.getElementById('check_progress').submit(); } setTimeout(checkprogress, 5000)</script>

Comment: That should work

Comment: @Quentin now working, sorry had typo timout instread of timeout, thanks

Comment: @Quentin but what I really want to do is remove the checkprogress form and just have the javascript submit direct to server, how would I do this ?